# Different structure in a conan repository in Artifactory

Tags: artifactory, conan

I've noticed a different repository structure for a conan repository in Artifactory. 
1. Artifactory Enterprise **6.3.2**
Repository Layout: `conan-default`
Repository strucutre: `repository_name/conan_username/conan_package_name/version/channel`
 2. Artifactory Enterprise **5.4.6**
Repository Layout: `conan-default`
Repository strucutre: `repository_name/conan_package_name/version/conan_username/channel`
Do you know why? Is it because the Artifactory version? I haven't found anything in Artifactory release notes related to the conan repository structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default layout for conan packages was migrated in Artifactory 6, to match other package managers default layouts that put the user (organization) name first, as the most important classification of packages.

The migration should be automatic, and affect only the visual appearance in Artifactory web UI. If there is some other changes, or the conan client breaks (and this is the reason you are asking), then, it is a failing migration in Artifactory upgrade. It should be reported to JFrog and ask support to help recover it.